# Calcular data de vencimento do contrato experiência

Tags: php

Preciso de criar uma tela que calcule automaticamente as datas de vencimento do contrato de experiência.

O usuário digita a data inicial e já me mostra a data que vence o contrato no caso 45 dias ou 90 dias.

Alguém poderia me dar uma dica?
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: 45 dias úteis ou 45 dias corridos?

Comment: 45 dias corridos

Comment: Se a  a resposta foi útil, você pode marcar uma delas, jovem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com a classe `DateTime`, você pode fazer assim:

```
$vencimento = (new Datetime())->modify('+45 days');
```

Como você disse que o usuário vai digitar a data inicial, provalmente ele digitará essa data no formato português (`d/m/Y`).

Nesse caso, sugiro que você `Datetime::createFromFormat`, para converter a data em português para um objeto `DateTime`.

Faça dessa forma:

```
$data_do_input_em_portugues = '10/02/2016';

$vencimento = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data_do_input_em_portugues)
                     ->modify('+45 days');
```

Answer (score 5):

Função [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php) resolve

```
$vencimento = strtotime("+45 day");
echo date("Y/m/d", $vencimento);
```